# AMD Radeon r9 Not connecting to HDMI screen?

Tags: graphics-card, hdmi, tv, amd-radeon

I have a custom built Windows gaming PC, we are using the Sapphire Radeon r9 gfx card and when we attempt to connect to monitor (or rather, HDMI TV) it does not connect, for a second it appears that it will then the "no signal" screen appears on the TV. The TV is a Westinghouse 32" LED TV with HDMI supports pretty high resolution. Could the issue be that the TV is a little old (approx. 3 years old) or is there some other issue we could have missed. We have tried the connection both with VGA and HDMI, when we connect to the motherboard graphics it works fine, we can see everything, hear everything but when we connect it to the graphics card the tv receives no signal. Any suggestions??? On a side note, we are pretty new to the whole computer building thing... So if you have a complicated answer please explain as best you can so I can understand what I should try and do. Thanks, so much, for your time.

Comment: It may be HDMI version problem. TV's too old.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the graphics drivers for your video card yet?  They should install automatically with Windows Update, but if not, you can grab them from [here](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download).  They'll generally be required in order to get the video outputs working as intended.

Also, you need to right click on your Windows desktop, and go to where you change the screen resolution.  When you're there, make sure it shows multiple displays available; you might need to change the one that's grayed out to "Extend this display" in order for Windows to output to that monitor.

Have you ensured the TV works with that HDMI port?  Do you have a DVD player, Xbox, something with HDMI-out that you're sure works on the TV?  A dead port is another possibility.  If you have a device that works this way, you can also try using the same cord from your PC->TV, to ensure it's not a bad cord you're using.

Comment: We actually ended up taking it in to a shop and having them double check all of our connections, we have been having this issue for a while, everything involving hardware is working fine, they tested it, checked everything and had it working fine. When we got it home we plugged it up... nothing, drivers are installed as can be seen by the fact that the computer works fine when the graphics card is unplugged and we use the onboard graphics, we can see the files for the drivers etc, but when we plug into the gfx it doesn't display anything through the tv. we are using the same cord etc.

Comment: when we plug into the onboard connections, the cord is brand new out of the box and works fine, not a cord issue, also not a dead port. It seems to be some kind of issue with the gfx card interfacing with the tv I THINK. We use the same card with the motherboard (gfx unplugged) and it displays fine, plug the card in and use the cord there no such luck, the tv almost displays and then it does nothing. But the drivers are indeed installed.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue. In the end, it was my TV that didn't want to work properly. I had a friend bring over his monitor, Dell, and it worked just fine. The graphics card had both pci-e 6-pin connectors plugged up to the graphics card and windows 7 booted right up with the graphics card working. I am going to buy a monitor and not hook up my pc to my TV. Thank you all for your time.