# Can a TV not read a pc signal?

Tags: video, graphics-card, tv

My TV, Westinghouse 32 inch TV (3 years old), is not reading any signal from my custom built pc. I am using a Radeon r9 270x graphics card with both pci ports connected to the graphics card. When I plug in one pci-e 6 pin connector into the card, the video output works, but the graphics card isn't being detected from my motherboard. When both pci-e 6 pin connectors are plugged into the card, there is no video signal going to the tv, just sound. My bios are up to date and the graphics card configuration is set to PEG and not IGD. I am wondering if it is my TV that cannot handle my pc or should I just buy a monitor that is meant for pc's so that there is video output when both pci-e connectors are connected to the video card. Thank you for your time.

Comment: What do you call a PCI port? you can plug a card IN a PCI port, but that was in '1995

Comment: My bad. I am using two pci-e power connectors to run my graphics card. The problem with that is that there is no video signal going to my TV. if I just plug in one pci-e connector to the graphics card, there is video and audio to the TV, but the graphics card is not showing up on my motherboard and thus isn't working.

Comment: How is the TV connected to the PC?  Specifically, what ports, cable, and video or tuner card?

Comment: @TylerSandell Edit that into your question. Use the edit link under the tags.

Comment: Am I correct in understanding from your [previous question](http://superuser.com/questions/789439/amd-radeon-r9-not-connecting-to-hdmi-screen) that the onboard HDMI port to the TV works when you don't have both power connectors to the r9, but when you do have both power connectors attached to the r9, there is no video from either the r9 or the onboard HDMI?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Lots of possibilities here, though the first guess would be a driver issue with the r9.  BIOS configuration could also play a role (you might enable onboard video with an external card to help troubleshoot).

Comment: I have changed the graphics configuration setting in my bios from the igd (default setting) to the PEG setting. My drivers are installed and my bios are up to date.

Comment: Update the question to reflect the correct information.

Comment: How many watts is your power supply?  It sounds like it is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tell your OS (Windows, Linux, etc) to send the video output to that card? What resolution is it set at?

Without knowing the model of the TV, look up the manual and see what it requires for input. I'm assuming you're using HDMI, so it should be safe to be at 720p or 1080p. In Windows, try setting your output to the HDMI port, and the resolution to 1080x1920, and make sure it's at 60Hz.

Do you see the BIOS logo or the 'Starting Windows' logo on the TV? If so, the computer detects it just fine. What power supply do you have? Can it run that video card comfortably?